# updated rbenv rails not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I have updated all the brew formulas with `brew update && brew upgrade`. I after I upgrading I noticed that rails is not found but when I type

```
which rails
```

it returns `/usr/bin/rails`. All I can guess is I have to add rails path to `.zshrc` again. But, I am not sure what all I need to add to `.zshrc` file.

What are all the things that update broke.

**.zshrc file**

```
# Adding bin to PATH for sublime
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"

# Rbenv stores data under ~/.rbenv by default. If you absolutely need to
# store everything under Homebrew's prefix, include this in your profile:
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv

# MongoDB

export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.7
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin

# Ruby Motion android tool
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/ndk

export DOTFILES=$HOME/.dotfiles
export ZSH=$DOTFILES/zsh

# display how long all tasks over 10 seconds take
export REPORTTIME=10

[[ -e ~/.terminfo ]] && export TERMINFO_DIRS=~/.terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo

# define the code directory
# This is where my code exists and where I want the `c` autocomplete to work from exclusively
if [[ -d ~/code ]]; then
    export CODE_DIR=~/code
fi

# source all .zsh files inside of the zsh/ directory
for config ($ZSH/**/*.zsh) source $config

if [[ -a ~/.localrc ]]; then
    source ~/.localrc
fi


# initialize autocomplete
autoload -U compinit
compinit

for config ($ZSH/**/*completion.sh) source $config

export EDITOR='nvim'

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# add /usr/local/sbin
if [[ -d /usr/local/sbin ]]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
fi

# adding path directory for custom scripts
export PATH=$DOTFILES/bin:$PATH

# check for custom bin directory and add to path
if [[ -d ~/bin ]]; then
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
fi

[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color

# install rbenv
if hash rbenv 2>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

if [[ -d ~/.rvm ]]; then
    PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
fi

# alias git to hub
if hash hub 2>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(hub alias -s)"
fi

# source nvm
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

if hash brew 2>/dev/null; then
    source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
    source `brew --prefix`/etc/profile.d/z.sh
fi


# Base16 Shell
# if [ -z "$THEME" ]; then
    export THEME="base16-eighties"
# fi
if [ -z "$BACKGROUND" ]; then
    export BACKGROUND="dark"
fi


BASE16_SHELL="$DOTFILES/.config/base16-shell/$THEME.$BACKGROUND.sh"
# [[ -s $BASE16_SHELL ]] && source $BASE16_SHELL
source $BASE16_SHELL

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  . $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh


# Online help for ZSH
  unalias run-help
  autoload run-help
  HELPDIR=/usr/local/share/zsh/help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came across is to re-install ruby & rails. I think while upgrading rbenv existing install somehow got removed

```
# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
ruby -v

gem install rails -v 4.2.4

rbenv rehash

rails -v
# Rails 4.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have Rails squirreled away in some particular gemset in some rvm-managed Ruby version, but you haven't told rvm to *use* it again yet.

Look at your installed Ruby versions (with `rvm list`).  Chances are that the one you were using before is still there.  If you recognize one, use it (with `rvm use ruby-2.2.4` or whatever version), else start looking in all the versions.

For each Ruby version you inspect, look at the gemsets rvm is managing under it (with `rvm gemset list`).  Chances are, you either created one for some Rails project, or as a starter for Rails projects in general (that's what I do), or maybe you just left all the gems to be installed into the `default` or `global` gemsets.

If you recognize a particular one, use it (with `rvm gemset use rails_4_2` or whatever gemset name), else start looking in all the gemsets.  You'll eventually find the right combination.

If you don't, then go through the same process as from scratch.  First make sure you're using the Ruby version you want (you may need to install it, with `rvm install 2.3` or whatever version).  Then create a new gemset (with `rvm gemset use --create rails_4_2` or whatever you want to call it).  Lastly, `gem install rails`.

Comment: I am using rbenv not rvm

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this manner:

1) sudo apt-get update

2) sudo apt-get install -y ruby-build

3) git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

4) rbenv install 2.3.0

5) rbenv global 2.3.0